# response : unauthorized in Swagger via RestSharp

Tags: vb.net, api, post, swagger, restsharp

I need to use an API from Swagger that sends email but I am having a problem in authorization I passed the token but still the result is Unauthorized.

I use the code below.

```
   `Dim url = "test123/test.com" (can't include the actual)
    Dim apiKey = "12312"
    Dim apiPassword = "12312"
    Dim client = New RestClient(url)
    Dim request = New RestRequest("token", Method.POST)
    request.Parameters.Clear()
    request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password")
    request.AddParameter("username", apiKey)
    request.AddParameter("password", apiPassword)
    Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
    _pristrKey = response.Content
    Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content)`
```

Now I have the Token in _pristrKey

Then I do this for email sending.

```
   `Dim url = "test123/test.com"
    Dim client = New RestClient(url)
    Dim request = New RestRequest("api/email", Method.POST)
    request.Parameters.Clear()
    request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json")
    request.AddParameter("Authorization", String.Format($"Bearer " + 
    _pristrKey), ParameterType.HttpHeader)
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    Dim apiInput = New With {Key .bulkId = "123", Key .from = 
    "test123@gmail.com", Key .subject = "Test", Key .text = "Test123", Key 
    .to = "test321@gmail.com"}
    request.AddParameter("application/json", 
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiInput), ParameterType.RequestBody)
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
    Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)`
```

Actual Output: `response = "StatusCode: Unauthorized, Content-Type: , Content-Length: 0)"`

Comment: You might need to troubleshoot this with the vendor/developer of the API that you are calling.

Comment: I am now getting this. {WWW-Authenticate=Bearer error="invalid_token"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because your token is invalid check your token if you got it right, also check for extra double quote(") in the token. I have encounter this in vb.net just use:

`.Replace("""", "").Trim()`